# Carrying misconcepts from previous editions - is this Question fine?

Tags: discussion

## Context

Recently, we got [this question about Wizard spellcasting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122505/43856). It was closed as a dupe and, from the OP comments and my answer being accepted, it's clear that he was carrying over a concept from Pathfinder to the 5e which was simply wrong.

This problem is pretty frequent, see [this confusion for 3.x players](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/44736/can-a-spell-be-prepared-once-and-cast-multiple-times) as well.

From my experience, this is a common issue from players coming from 3.5e or Pathfinder to the fifth edition, mainly when they were used to play **only** 3.5e/PF and not other systems as well. It happened to me when I started playing 5e, it happened to an entire group of players I DM'd to. It keeps happening now and then when someone decides to try out 5e after playing 3.5e for 15 years. Point being it happens frequently.

The thing is: these questions don't reflect, from my point of view, the real problem. "Can a spell be prepared once and cast multiple times?", "Do wizards get bonus spell slots from intelligence?" are questions easily answered by reading the PHB, and yet experienced players (that are able to read, and usually **did** read the PHB) still get confused because the problem is not the ruling of the current system, but them carrying misconceptions from the previous one.

I think that question and answers **focusing** (instead of just mentioning) on the **differences between editions** rather than just "How this edition works" might help these 3.5e players during their transition. I wanted to create a Question that they might refer to when doing so. The thing is: I want to focus on the fact that the editions/systems are different and the general "confusion" that happens, not on a specific question like "Can I prepare more spells than I can cast? What I do with them?"

## The Question

Obviously this will get edited by me and the community many times if it gets posted, but the sketch follows.

**Title**: "Coming from 3.5e/PF, I'm confused on how prepared spellcasting works"

**Body**: In D&D 3.x, Wizards would prepare spells and cast them, while Sorcerers were spontaneous casters, which could cast any spell they knew as many times as their spell slots let them. The concept of preparing spells still exists in 5e, but Wizards now also have spell slots.

From the Wizard's class table, I have two spell slots at 1st level. But I can prepare a number different from that. Should I be using the minimum between both? More broadly, how can I translate 3.5e/Pathfinder spellcasting to the current Prepared Spellcasting?

## My Meta Question

I feel this either gets too broad or becomes a duplicate of the linked questions (or many other questions about Wizard's spellcasting). For example, in the current state of the question, it's two questions in one - the first is already answered more than once and the second is too broad. I really like the idea of the question but I can't write it in a way it seems decent.

So, is my reasoning for the question valid? I.e., should this question actually exist or I'm just overthinking things? And if it should, how can I make it stackable, not too broad or duplicate?

Answer (score 6):

I agree with your initial feeling that such a question about "how can I translate 3.5e/Pathfinder spellcasting to the current Prepared Spellcasting" would be too broad, even as a signpost. More specific formulations of it are already covered by the duplicates you mention. I don't think we really need such a "signpost" question; the people asking those kinds of question clearly have not seen the existing questions that already cover the issue, so I doubt yet another question asking the same thing would really accomplish much.

If you do encounter other common misconceptions that haven't already been asked here (and aren't too broad), you could probably try and ask those on RPG.SE.